# Ruby: call initialize method before others in class

Tags: ruby, class, methods

I have a file with the following code
and i want the initialize method to run first and then call

```
class Lol < Redstone

    def initialize
        super 2013
    end

    call "/" do |headers|
        "headers"
    end

end
```

But when i execute this, the method call is first called.
how to fix this?

Comment: Please explain what are you trying to achieve

Comment: Put the call to `call` inside the `initialize` method. At the moment it's being called when you declare the class, before any instance is created. (At least, I think that's what you're angling at.)

Comment: "I want the initialize method to run first and then the call method"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`initialize` is an instance method in this class, so the `def initialize` is just setting up the constructor for the class. `call..` is calling the *class's* `call` method at the time the class definition is parsed. This code is equivalent to

```
class Lol < Redstone
  def initialize
    super 2013
  end
end

Lol.call "/" do |headers|
  "headers"
end
```

(assuming call is a public class method)

Ruby doesn't really have the idea of a class constructor, other than the code in the actual class definition (like the `call` method). If you need to do something, you could do:

```
class Lol < Redstone
  def self.init
    #do class setup
  end
  init
  def initialize
    super 2013
  end

  call "/" do |headers|
    "headers"
  end
end
```

However, depending on the way you are wanting this to work, that may not do what you want.